# Кастомизация класса с помощью метакласса в питоне

Tags: python, metaclass

Всем привет. Задание заключается в том, чтобы с помощью метакласса создавать собственный класс, где все атрибуты и методы (кроме магических) назывались по правилу prefix_nameofaatribute. В целом, мне  удалось этого добиться, но только не для атрибутов, инициализируемых в **init**. Более при попытке создания класса, выдает ошибку "TypeError: CustomClass() takes no arguments". Как мне это исправить? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
class CustomMeta(type):
    prefix = 'custom_'

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in dct.items() if not name.startswith('__'))
        custom_attrs = dict((CustomMeta.prefix + name, value) for name, value in attrs)
        return super(CustomMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, custom_attrs)


class CustomClass(metaclass=CustomMeta):
    x = 50

    def __init__(self, val = 99):
        self.val = val

    def line(self):
        return 100


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inst = CustomClass(4)
    inst.custom_x
    inst.custom_val
    inst.custom_line()

    inst.x  # должна быть ошибка
    inst.val  # должна быть ошибка
    inst.line()  # должна быть ошибка
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка создания объекта заключается в том, что при создании класса, вы стёрли упоминание `__init__` функции.  Также, пусть мне никогда не понять зачем вам это, однако подмену названий атрибутов в дочернем конструкторе - это такое себе занятие. Вы всегда можете переопределить функции `__setattr__`, `__getattr__` и `__delattr__`, однако наличие подобного функционала сломало бы работу `__slots__` механизма. Более того, IDE не смогут узнать о наличии "новых" имён аттрибутов.

Если вы хотите скрыть какие-либо переменные от дочерних классов и внешнего доступа - используйте двойное подчёркивание перед названием атрибута. Внутри класса оно продолжит быть `__var_name`, однако снаружи придётся писать `__ClassName_var_name`

Исправленное создание объекта класса:

```py
class CustomMeta(type):
    prefix = 'custom_'

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        custom_attrs = {
            name if name.startswith('__') else f'{mcs.prefix}{name}': value
            for name, value in dct.items()
        }
        return super(CustomMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, custom_attrs)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это просто задание на метаклассы) Огромное спасибо за помощь!